# Kotlin clear an adapter

Tags: android, kotlin

What is the best way to clear an adapter in Kotlin?
I was trying to clear a recyclerview and update the values. 
I am using LoaderManager and I am kind of stuck in this state.

Comment: post your code what have you done so far

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want update `recyclerview`  after adding/removing data in your `adapter` use this code

If you use `Arraylist` to store the data objects then just clear your `list` and call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

```
         dataList.clear()
         recyclerView?.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
```